# two AWS accounts from one laptop

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I have two AWS accounts, one for learning and one for business. I am using the work laptop to follow some AWS courses. Is it a problem to connect to my private AWS account to the same laptop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AWS CLI allows you to store multiple named [profiles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-profiles.html) (access credentials) on the one machine, and specify which one to use when running a particular command. If no profile is specified, it will use the default profile, which is the credentials you specify when you do `aws configure`.

**To create a named profile:**

```sh
aws configure --profile=<name>
```

.. and enter in the relevant access key and secret when prompted.

**To use the named profile:** 
[This page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/) describes a set of options that you can use with any AWS CLI command, one of which is `--profile` (same as when using `aws configure`). Select a profile to use for a given command like so:

```sh
aws --profile=<name> [other options] <command> <subcommand> [parameters]
```

I believe you can also add `--profile` to the end of a command rather than at the start.

Comment: Actually  i have problem now, i switch to my private account ( i used access & secret key) but now i don't know how to switch to my work account and i don't have thoese keys because all the configuration has been made by the company IT, how can i fix that. i am totaly new to aws

Comment: If you switched to your private account by using `aws configure` (without `--profile`), then your company access keys have been overwritten in the file that they are stored (`%UserProfile%\.aws\credentials` on Windows, `~/.aws/credentials` on Unix). You will need to get your access credentials from your company again. Or, if you have access to the [AWS Console](console.aws.amazon.com), you can view your access key and secret from there (go to the IAM service).

Comment: You cannot retrieve a Secret Key from the IAM console. It is only provided immediately after the IAM User is created. If the company cannot provide the existing Secret Key, then a new Access Key + Secret Key will need to be generated. (Nice to see you here, Brads!)

Comment: @RAZ Sorry, John is right. If you have access to the console though you could possibly regenerate your secret key, depending on your permissions. Otherwise you're stuck asking your company for another set of credentials.

Comment: thanks @JohnRotenstein and brads, i will ask for that from my company